# How would I find power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(3^nx^n) \over n!} $ radius and interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(3^nx^n) \over n!} $$

I have no idea how to start this problem, the only thing that looks familiar is $x^n/n!$ which I know as a sequence goes to 0 when you take the limit, but I don't know if that applies here.

Comment: Your series equals $e^{3x}$. The exponential is an entire function.

Comment: $3^n x^n=(3x)^n$. Define $y=3x$ and get something you know.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = \frac{3^nx^n}{n!}$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{n+1}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{3^nx^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3x}{n+1} = 0$$

No matter where you evaluate your series for $x$, the ratio test shows that you will always have convergence.

Answer (score 0):

use the ratio test 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(3x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{(3x)^n}=\frac{(3x)(n)!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{3x}{n+1}$$
that means the series converge for any value of $x$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how 3x/n+1 means any value of x will converge?

Comment: @Jay When the $n\rightarrow \infty $ the term becomes zero. We know that the condition of  converge is when the limit less than 1

Comment: Oh Right! that makes sense, thanks